# Woocommerce Shortcode for edit and add Shipping Address

Tags: php, woocommerce, shortcode

I am trying to render a portion of the *Woocommerce - My Account* section. Specifically the form for editing or adding a Shipping Address (*myaccount/form-edit-address.php*). By default the Shortcode I created shows the *Billing Address*. I can't figure out how to pass a variable or specify that I want the **Shipping Address** part of the code.

This is the Shortcode for the Billing Address:

```
add_shortcode('edit_address', 'display_myaccount_edit_address');
function display_myaccount_edit_address()
{
    return WC_Shortcode_My_Account::edit_address();
}
```

And I am trying to achieve it doing this (it doesn't work obviously)

```
add_shortcode('edit_address_shipping', 'display_myaccount_edit_address_shipping');
function display_myaccount_edit_address_shipping()
{
    return WC_Shortcode_My_Account::edit_address_shipping($load_address = 'Shipping address');
}
```

Any idea how to do it? Any help would be pretty much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the key to pass is 'shipping':
So the function for shortcode will look like this:

```
    function display_myaccount_edit_address_shipping()
    {
        return WC_Shortcode_My_Account::edit_address_shipping('shipping');
    }

    add_shortcode('edit_address_shipping', 'display_myaccount_edit_address_shipping');
```

https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_shortcode_my_accountedit_address/

Comment: Thanks a lot niknak. That solve my problem!